# Adding document to my Maven site report

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

We have a document that's in Markdown we want to be available in our Maven site reports. I've found a plugin that translate Markdown into HTML, and I place the generated HTML document in `target/documents/README.html`. I'd like to include this document in the generate site report, but the documentation for the maven-site-plugin is a bit sparse:

> How do I Integrate static (X)HTML pages into my Maven site?
>   You can integrate your static pages by following these steps:
>
> - Put your static pages in the resources directory, ${basedir}/src/site/resources
> - Create your site.xml and put it in ${basedir}/src/site
> - Link to the static pages by modifying the menu section, create items and map them to the filenames of the static pages

Wow, that's clear!

This document is stored in `${basedir}/src/markdown/README.md` and is generated as an HTML document in `target/documents/README.html`. I could change the directories where everything occurs, but I don't want to write a generated HTML document to `${basedir}/src/site`.

How do I generate my own `site.xml`? Can I get `site.xml` to pull documents from another directory under `target` instead?

Comment: Simply put the docs int src/site/markdown/.. and it should work (Take care if you are using a uptodate version of maven-site-plugin.

Comment: That worked -- part way. It produces a file `target/site/README.html`, but there's no link I could find to that particular page.

Comment: You need to create the link in your other pages or from the `src/site/site.xml` descriptor...

Comment: @khmarbaise - I actually got an example of `site.xml` from someone. What the documentation doesn't state is that it pre-pends menu items to the existing `index.html` page. That is, I don't have to recreate the whole index, just put the links I need. I'll add a full answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ends up not being as difficult as I thought it would be. The `site.xml` documentation is bad, but I found an example, played around with it, and figured out how to do it:

First, I followed khmarbaise's advice and put the document under `src/site/markdown/README.md`. That produced a `target/site/README.html` document when `site` ran. However, there was no link to it.

The next thing I had to do was produce a `src/site/site.xml` file. All I had to do was create the required link and not the whole `index.html` page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project>
    <body>
        <menu name="Configuration">
            <item name="Using this library" href="README.html"/>
        </menu>
        <menu ref="reports"/>
    </body>
</project>
```

The `<menu ref="reports"/>` was needed to keep the other report menus.

You can see the results here:

[image: Added Markdown document in menu]

Note the added *Configuration* section.

The only other thing I did was also use Rule of Tech [markdown plugin](http://ruleoftech.com/2013/maven-plugin-to-generate-html-from-markdown). This way, I could link the generated HTML to the archived artifacts link in Jenkins.

Comment: If the documentation as you mentioned is bad do you have suggestions to improve it? May be you create an appropriate [JIRA ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSITE) with your suggestions so the docs can be made better.